# ls : sort as: 1 2 12 ( Side by Side )

Tags: ls, sort

I understand commands such as

```
ls | sort -n
```

can do certain sorting.. but I would like Horizontal sorting just as it's being done via "**ls**" command.

**Test** in Empty folder:

```
 touch 1 2 12
```

with **ls** command

```
ls
1  12  2
```

What I want to see is:

```
1  2  12
```

Horizontally just like the "**ls**" command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the BSD-inclined who do not have GNU coreutils installed and therefore can't use `ls -v`:

```
 $ printf '%s\n' * | sort -n | column
 1       2       12
```

The `printf` will generate a list of names, each on its own line.  The `sort` will sort these numerically.  The `column` utility will arrange these into columns, much like what `ls` does by default.

Answer (score 3):

Using the command `ls -v` will give you the desired output:

```
1 2 12
```